# flyspell error enabling with nuspell

Tags: flyspell

I want to use nuspell as my spellchecker for emacs. I have installed dictionary and it works fine when I call the program from terminal. But I got the following msg in emacs:

```
Error enabling Flyspell mode:
(nuspell exited with code 1)
```

Here is my setting for flyspell;

```
(setq
  ispell-program-name
  "nuspell")
(setq ispell-hunspell-dict-paths-alist
      '(("en_US" "/usr/share/hunspell/en_US.aff")))
(setq ispell-local-dictionary "en_US")
```

`nuspell -v` is the version information. `nuspell -vv` isn't an valid argument.

```
~ ❱ nuspell -v
nuspell 4.2.0
Copyright (C) 2016-2020 Dimitrij Mijoski and Sander van Geloven
License LGPLv3+: GNU LGPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Dimitrij Mijoski and Sander van Geloven.
~ ❱ aspell -vv
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Aspell 0.60.8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A brief look at the code (in Emacs 27.1 and also a recent build of 28) suggests that `ispell`, `aspell`, `hunspell`, and `enchant` are all supported.  There is no mention of `nuspell` in the code.

Is `nuspell` compatible with any of the supported programs in how it should be invoked, and the output it produces?  I.e. is there a reasonable expectation that this ought to be working?

The detection of the specific program being used is based on all of them accepting a `-vv` option and identifying themselves as *ostensibly* ispell, "but really Aspell 0.60.7-20110707" (for example).

What does `nuspell -vv` display?

Unless it uses that same output to announce itself as one of the supported programs, I suspect it won't work out of the box.

(Whether or not it can be *made* to work without custom support being added would probably depend on how compatible it is with the other programs.)

Comment: I think you are right. `nuspell` probably doesn't work with `flyspell` out of box. For some reasons I thought it's similar to `hunspell`. I installed `aspell` instead and now it works.

Comment: Yeah, it *sounds* like it's supposed to be similar to hunspell.  I'm still interested to know what `nuspell -vv` says (or `nuspell -v` if it doesn't like `-vv`).  If the actual spell-checking output is compatible, then it's probably not difficult to add support for it by recognising its version string.

Comment: i've updated the output in my post. Doesn't seem very meaning to me.